# Add simple text/description to a page in Rails Admin

Tags: rails-admin

Is there a way to add text to a page in rails admin? I'd like to add a description to a page. I know the label can be edited, but I'd like to be able to add a description to a page underneath the label.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no builtin way to do that, but you can do it like this:

1. You have to override the file where rails admin puts that title but placing a copy of the [original file](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/pjax.html.haml) on your own project
   app/views/layouts/rails_admin/pjax.html.haml
2. Then you can access your model like this on that file:

```
.page-header
  %h1= @page_name
  %div
    = @abstract_model.model.your_awesome_description
```

3. And in your model you just need to add a class method

```rb
class QualifiedUsers < ApplicationRecord
  def self.your_awesome_description
    'These users are greeeat'
  end
end
```

If you want a description per object, you have @object available on pjax and you just add the instance method.

I know is not that maintainable to override default partials, but rails_admin give us no option to do this and i figured this is the lest intrusive you can do what you want.